# Unity2d how to turn human to zombie

Tags: unity-game-engine

im creating a zombie game I want my human characters become my zombie character when the human hp turn to 0 or when it die. But I'm stuck wondering how? any suggestion what topic or lesson where i can learn this?

Comment: Lern what prefabs are in Unity3D. Basic knowledge of Object-oriented programming is also necessary. There are too many ways of achieving what you want, and it all depends on case to case basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your zombie model as a child of human model. So the zombie would move with human target. Initially your zombie model has to be setactive as false. When the hp of human is 0 then you can access the child of human model and use setactive(true). and then you can make zombie.transform.parent = null. Then human.setactive(false). Of course this all depends on your prefab or case how you want to use it.